# How to pass an array variable of a struct to another function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, typedef

I am pretty new to using typedef struct, so I hope you'll be able to give pretty basic explanation so I can understand better.

I have declared an array variable called `ExpNum[3]` for my typedef struct. I want to be able to pass `ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]` and so on and so forth to another function called `myfunction()`. However, I am not able to do

> > pstInputs->ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]

When I run my codes as shown below, the values initialized here do not even get passed. I figure this out because I `printf` `ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]` in the main function and `myfunction()` and the values are different. The one in the main function is correct while the one in `myfunction()` printed random long numbers, an error. I know why there is an error. My question is how should I pass this array? Is it even possible in the first place?

I know an easier method is to pass the structure without declaring `ExpNum[3]`. However this is crucial because my actual programme deals with more Experiments and I need `ExpNum[3]` to help users ensure that they do not mix up the `ValueofParamOne`, `ValueofParamTwo` and it's corresponding `ExperimentResults`

Or maybe I should change my method entirely? My main focus is to make sure users assign their values accurately.

`myfunction()` is highly technical and mathematical. Its purpose is to calculate the optimized parameter values. Of course, in my actual function there are more than 3 experiment data.

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned int     NumofParam;
double     ExperimentResults[3];
double     ValueofParamOne[3];
double     ValueofParamTwo[3];
}EXP_CONDITION;

int main()
{
EXP_CONDITION stInputs;
EXP_CONDITION* pstInputs;
pstInputs = &stInputs;

pstInputs->NumofParam = 2U;
EXP_CONDITION ExpNum[3];

/*assign values to Experiment 1*/
ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]=200;
ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[0]=400;
ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[0]=1000;

/*assign values to Experiment 2*/
ExpNum[1].ValueofParamOne[1]=210;
ExpNum[1].ValueofParamTwo[1]=440;
ExpNum[1].ExperimentResults[1]=2000;

/*assign values to Experiment 3*/
ExpNum[2].ValueofParamOne[2]=220;
ExpNum[2].ValueofParamTwo[2]=480;
ExpNum[2].ExperimentResults[2]=3000;

myfunction(&stInputs);
return 0;
}
```

Editted based on the comments from @MaxVollmer and @aschepler :)

Comment: Why not create a class Expcondition with a proper constructor and use std::vector for storing the values? Then depending on your function, you can pass your vector using const or non const reference to the vector.

Comment: Fun fact: C++ has no need for `typedef struct`. `struct EXP_CONDITION { ... };` contains all the information the compiler needs in order to use the `EXP_CONDITION ` identifier. Sound like someone is teaching you C, not C++.

Comment: Puzzled. You don't seem to be trying to pass the array anywhere. You may have simplified your example too much.

Comment: *"When I run my codes as shown below, the values initialized here do not even get passed."* That's because you aren't passing them. `stInputs` and `ExpNum` are not related, and you're passing `stInputs`, not `ExpNum` to `myfunction`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry I'm unclear with what you mean by using std::vector

Comment: We need to see at least the declaration, and preferably a simple definition, of `myfunction` to guess what's going on. Ideally, you would create a [mcve] with a similar function, expected and actual output, that shows exactly why you conclude "the values do not get passed", so we don't need to just guess.

Comment: [A Beginner's Guide to std::vector](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) ?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. In C++ **don't** `typedef` a `struct`. Instead of `typedef struct{} Gah;`, write `struct Gah{}`.

Comment: *"I printf ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0] in the main function and myfunction() and the values are different."* Why would you expect whatever `ExpNum` you have in `myfunction` to have the same values as the `ExpNum` in `main`, when you never pass the `ExpNum` in `main` to `myfunction`? It's as if I put a cake in my fridge, then drive to my friends house and am surprised that the cake isn't in my friend's fridge. Please add the code of `myfunction`, so we can properly help you fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line:

```
EXP_CONDITION stInputs;
```

you've constructed an object of the `EXP_CONDITION` struct. All it's members are uninitialized (i.e. "random").
You then create pointer to this struct and set the value of the `NumofParam` member. All other members remain uninitialized:

```
pstInputs = &stInputs;

pstInputs->NumofParam = 2U;
```

Now, and here's where your getting tripped up I think. You create an array of 3 more `EXP_CONDITION` structs. They are sitting somewhere else in memory. Modifying these structs *will not* modify the original `stInputs` object that you declare above.

EXP_CONDITION ExpNum[3];

You finally pass a pointer to the original `stInputs` object to your function. It is still uninitialized.

Now, when you are assigning results, you have 2 levels of array, where it's not clear why. For example:

```
/*assign values to Experiment 2*/
ExpNum[1].ValueofParamOne[1]=210;
ExpNum[1].ValueofParamTwo[1]=440;
ExpNum[1].ExperimentResults[1]=2000;
```

assigns the values to the second `ExpNum` (which seems fine), but then you assign it to the second index in the arrays inside the struct (e.g. `ExpNum[1].ValueofParamTwo[0]` is unintialized).

So, my guess as to what you want: Start with a top level structure that will hold all your experiments, then create a separate structure to hold each experiment's results.

```
typedef struct 
{
    double     ExperimentResults;
    double     ValueofParamOne;
    double     ValueofParamTwo;
} ExperimentData;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int     NumofParam;
    ExperimentData     experiments[3];
} EXP_CONDITION;
```

and you can assign the values like this:

```
EXP_CONDITION stInputs;

stInputs.NumofParam = 2U;

stInputs.experiments[0].ValueofParamOne = 200;
stInputs.experiments[0].ValueofParamTwo = 400;
stInputs.experiments[0].ExperimentResults =  1000;

stInputs.experiments[1].ValueofParamOne = 210;
stInputs.experiments[1].ValueofParamTwo = 440;
stInputs.experiments[1].ExperimentResults =  2000;

// etc . . .
```

Comment: Hello thank you for this answer. I can safely say you understand what i'm trying to do with my data. I tried this method. However I'm getting an error at `ExperimentData experiments[3]`. It says: `error C3646`: 'experiments': unknown override specifier
`error C2143`: syntax error: missing ',' before '['
`error C2143`: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
`error C2238`: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: It looks like you have typo, do you have an open ( bracket somewhere?

Comment: You were right. Thank you for the detailed explanation about how my initial arrays for `ValueofParamOne` was not appropriate. I followed your method. It gave me the solution I was looking for! Would have never thought of adding another struct

Answer (score 3):

It is quite apparent that you are just a little bit confused on how to put the values together into a single struct to make use of all values at once.

In your code. You assign a value to your `stInputs.NumofParam` -- but no other values are assigned.

You then declare an array of 3-struct in `ExpNum`, but then inexplicably assign only one row of values in each struct?

From the gist of your question, it looks like you are trying to fill one struct with all values so you can pass that struct to `myfunction` (which we will presume does something like output all values in the struct)

Before looking at fixes, let's look at some general coding issues.

First, don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where absolutely required like with the `scanf` *field-width* modifier). Your `3` is a *magic number*. Instead, If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more), or use a global `enum` to do the same thing. That way you have one single place at the top of your code to change things if needed and you don't have to go picking through your declarations or loop limits to change things, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXV 3  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {
    unsigned int     NumofParam;
    double     ExperimentResults[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamOne[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamTwo[MAXV];
} EXP_CONDITION;
```

Next, C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Now on to your code. First (and especially if you will be looping over elements in an array) **initialize your structs to all zero** when declared. That will eliminate the chance of invoking *Undefined Behavior* by inadvertently attempting to read from an uninitialized value. You can either use a *named initializer* for the first member (all others will be set zero by default), or you can use the *universal initializer* (e.g. `{0}`) to accomplish the same thing. Example:

```
int main (void)
{
    /* initialize your struct to all zero using a named initializer
     * or the universal intializer {0}
     */
    EXP_CONDITION stInputs = { .NumofParam = 0 };
    EXP_CONDITION* pstInputs;
    pstInputs = &stInputs;
    ...
    EXP_CONDITION ExpNum[MAXV] = {{ .NumofParam = 0 }};
```

Now look at the logic of your assignments. You declare 3 stucts in the array `ExpNum`. Each struct has within it 3 arrays of 3 values each, e.g.

```
    double     ExperimentResults[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamOne[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamTwo[MAXV];
```

When you attempt to fill each of `ExpNum[0]` `ExpNum[1]` and `ExpNum[2]` -- you are only filling one element, e.g.

```
    /*assign values to Experiment 1*/
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]=200;
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[0]=400;
    ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[0]=1000;

    /*assign values to Experiment 2*/
    ExpNum[1].ValueofParamOne[1]=210;
    ExpNum[1].ValueofParamTwo[1]=440;
    ExpNum[1].ExperimentResults[1]=2000;
    ...
```

To completely fill a single struct your would need

```
    /*assign values to Experiment 1*/
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]=200;
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[0]=400;
    ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[0]=1000;

    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[1]=210;
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[1]=440;
    ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[1]=2000;

    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[2]=220;
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[2]=480;
    ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[2]=3000;
```

Now let's look at `myfunction` which we will assume just outputs the values stored in each struct (this is just for example):

```
void myfunction (EXP_CONDITION *exp)
{
    printf ("\nNumofParam: %u\n", exp->NumofParam);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV; i++)
        printf (" %7.1lf    %7.1lf    %7.1lf\n", exp->ExperimentResults[i],
                exp->ValueofParamOne[i], exp->ValueofParamTwo[i]);

    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

Think about what will print if we call `myfunction (pstInputs)`? What will print if we call `myfunction (&ExpNum[0])`? Or `myfunction (&ExpNum[1])`

Hints:

```
Initial stInputs struct

NumofParam: 2
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0

Content of each of ExpNum structs

NumofParam: 0
  1000.0      200.0      400.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0


NumofParam: 0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
  2000.0      210.0      440.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0


NumofParam: 0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
  3000.0      220.0      480.0
```

I could be wrong, but logically, it seems you intended to have all experiments within your `stInputs` struct, and not sprinkled as one-row each in your `ExpNum` array. The beauty of coding and structs is that you can easily shuffle the data together to now put it in one place so you can manage the data properly. Simple loop over the `ExpNum` array and copy all data to the `stInputs` struct in its proper place, e.g.

```
    /* now put all values in your stInputs struct like it appears
     * you intended to do?
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV; i++) {
        pstInputs->ExperimentResults[i] = ExpNum[i].ExperimentResults[i];
        pstInputs->ValueofParamOne[i] = ExpNum[i].ValueofParamOne[i];
        pstInputs->ValueofParamTwo[i] = ExpNum[i].ValueofParamTwo[i];
    }
```

Now when you call `myfunction (pstInputs)` you get all of your data, e.g.

```
Output of the completely filled stInputs struct

NumofParam: 2
  1000.0      200.0      400.0
  2000.0      210.0      440.0
  3000.0      220.0      480.0
```

Putting all the pieces together, your final example could look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXV 3  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {
    unsigned int     NumofParam;
    double     ExperimentResults[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamOne[MAXV];
    double     ValueofParamTwo[MAXV];
} EXP_CONDITION;

void myfunction (EXP_CONDITION *exp)
{
    printf ("\nNumofParam: %u\n", exp->NumofParam);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV; i++)
        printf (" %7.1lf    %7.1lf    %7.1lf\n", exp->ExperimentResults[i],
                exp->ValueofParamOne[i], exp->ValueofParamTwo[i]);

    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}

int main (void)
{
    /* initialize your struct to all zero using a named initializer
     * or the universal intializer {0}
     */
    EXP_CONDITION stInputs = { .NumofParam = 0 };
    EXP_CONDITION* pstInputs;
    pstInputs = &stInputs;

    pstInputs->NumofParam = 2U;
    EXP_CONDITION ExpNum[MAXV] = {{ .NumofParam = 0 }};

    /*assign values to Experiment 1*/
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0]=200;
    ExpNum[0].ValueofParamTwo[0]=400;
    ExpNum[0].ExperimentResults[0]=1000;

    /*assign values to Experiment 2*/
    ExpNum[1].ValueofParamOne[1]=210;
    ExpNum[1].ValueofParamTwo[1]=440;
    ExpNum[1].ExperimentResults[1]=2000;

    /*assign values to Experiment 3*/
    ExpNum[2].ValueofParamOne[2]=220;
    ExpNum[2].ValueofParamTwo[2]=480;
    ExpNum[2].ExperimentResults[2]=3000;

    /* output your first stInputs struct */
    puts ("Initial stInputs struct");
    myfunction (&stInputs);

    /* output values in each of your ExpNum array of struct
     * (but note, you only assign one-row in each struct)
     */
    puts ("Content of each of ExpNum structs");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV; i++)
        myfunction (&ExpNum[i]);

    /* now put all values in your stInputs struct like it appears
     * you intended to do?
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV; i++) {
        pstInputs->ExperimentResults[i] = ExpNum[i].ExperimentResults[i];
        pstInputs->ValueofParamOne[i] = ExpNum[i].ValueofParamOne[i];
        pstInputs->ValueofParamTwo[i] = ExpNum[i].ValueofParamTwo[i];
    }

    /* output the completely filled stInputs struct */
    puts ("Output of the completely filled stInputs struct");
    myfunction (pstInputs);

    return 0;
}
```

**Full Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/expstruct
Initial stInputs struct

NumofParam: 2
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0

Content of each of ExpNum structs

NumofParam: 0
  1000.0      200.0      400.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0


NumofParam: 0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
  2000.0      210.0      440.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0


NumofParam: 0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
     0.0        0.0        0.0
  3000.0      220.0      480.0

Output of the completely filled stInputs struct

NumofParam: 2
  1000.0      200.0      400.0
  2000.0      210.0      440.0
  3000.0      220.0      480.0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If I have misinterpreted your question, just drop a comment or edit your question and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the `ExpNum` array, simply pass it. There really isn't much to it:

```
myfunction(ExpNum);
```

The compiler will actually pass a pointer to the first element in the array, but that doesn't matter. You know it's 3 elements (and if not, you can simply add a 2nd parameter to the function to provide the number of elements).

Inside `myfunction` you can then access the elements in the array like so:

```
void myfunction(EXP_CONDITION* expNum)
{
    double foo = expNum[0].ValueofParamOne[0];
    double bar = expNum[1].ValueofParamOne[0];
    double baz = expNum[2].ValueofParamOne[0];
    // ...
}
```